# PHP Upload to MySQL script with variable not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a php for uploading pictures onto server (which works) and updating url link in the database. (which doesn't)

The problem bit is like this:

```
< ?php

require_once('Db.php');
Db::connect('localhost', '***', '***', '***');

// ... some stuff for uploading files ...

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "File ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " was uploaded.";

           $_POST['path_url']= ".../images/". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);*            


           $query=Db::connect(
                   'UPDATE tab_digital SET `path_url`=(?) WHERE `id_digital`=(?)',
                    $_POST['path_url'], $_POST['id_digital'] 
            ); 
 }
? >
```

I tried echoing $_POST[''] both path_url and ID after that and it worked. (ID is from a simple input form)

Comment: Are you sure you need to use db::connect to execute a query? Where is your error handling?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have no idea whether I need db::connect, that's just the way I was taught. (And so far it worked for me well enough so I didn't really try to dabble in anything else.) And error handling is so far completely and utterly nonexistent.